# DLQ(SQS) json format populated by SNS notification

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

In my workflow, SNS triggers Lambda and I want to recover SNS notification in case of Lambda failures. My lambda is written to process SNS messages. However if lambda fails and SNS gets into DLQ (which is an SQS), I am wondering what will be the json format of SQS if I re-drive the DLQ into Lambda. Would it be the same as SNS or SQS will have its own json structure and body = {SNS}. If it is the former, I need to revise the lambda function to handle both SNS and SQS. Is there any other solution? Is there a way to pass SNS as-is into lambda using DLQ-SQS if lambda fails?

Thanks.

Comment: Try it out, and let us know what you find! You might also be interested in [Amazon SNS raw message delivery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried actually, SNS is belong to away team, hard to reach and re-drive to notification. I tried to write some wrong handler in lambda to make deliberate failure. It seems that with manual testing only sends empty notification, hence can not see what is going on. I have read raw message, I ll explore with away team if they can make it (probably not).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I asked to to re-drive, yes, as expected whole SNS is getting written into SQS body key.